# VB.Net When button click open another form

Tags: vb.net, forms, webforms, click

I'm opening a new form when clicking a button. But that form opening, only when click button second time. I want to open that when first time button click.
How to do this?

```
If Not Session("CheckAvailableItem") Is Nothing Then
    Session("CheckAvailableItem") = Nothing
    Session("CheckAvailableItem") = dt_detail
    ChkAvl.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { e.processOnServer = window.open('PreOrderItemAvailability.aspx' , '_blank',  'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, width=700px, height=500px;') }"                     
Else
    Session("CheckAvailableItem") = dt_detail
    ChkAvl.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { window.open('PreOrderItemAvailability.aspx', '_blank',  'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, width=700px, height=500px;') }"
End If
```